# ¿como obtener una fila fuera de un rango?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, sql

[image: tabla reserva]
Buenas amigos disculpen estoy trabajando en un proyecto para mi materia y me quede en un punto donde no he podido avanzar
lo que pasa es que quiero hacer una consulta sobre esa tabla donde compare el valor de 2 variables con las 2 columnas (fecha_entrada, fecha_salida) y me devuelva el idHabitacion pero de las fechas que no esten en el rango de las 2 columnas no se si me deje entender

Esto es lo que llevo al momento:

```
$habitacion = Habitacion::leftJoin("reservas", "reservas.idHabitacion", 
                                   "habitaciones.id") 
                        ->whereNotBetween('reservas.fecha_entrada', [$entrada, 
                                           $salida]) 
                        ->whereNotBetween('reservas.fecha_salida', [$entrada, 
                                           $salida]) 
                        ->where('habitaciones.condicion', '1') 
                        ->where('habitaciones.idCategoria', $categoria->id) 
                        ->get();
```

Comment: agrega por favor lo que lleves hecho o investigado al momento y las dudas puntuales que tienes

Comment: Solo una pequeña consulta pero no me ha funcionado

Comment: @Aprendiz buenas que tal haber te explico lo que pasa es que en mi tabla de la BD guardo un rango en dos columnas como se ve en la imagen **fecha_entrada y fecha_salida** y lo que quiero es registrar otra fila pero que este fuera de ese rango para eso quiero hacer una consulta donde me devuelva si es que esta registrado el **idHabitacion** si esta fuera del rango que quiero ingresar y si no esta que tome otra habitacion y le haga resera


espero haberme hecho entender

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, lo que pido que agregues por favor en tu edición es lo que llevas hecho

Comment: @Aprendiz
ese supuestatemente es mi codigo para  obtener una habitacion disponible donde le paso por parametro la fecha de entrada(entrada) y la fecha de salida (salida)

Comment: @Aprendiz ya encontre una forma de hacerlo ahora creo que esta bien solo que tiene un pequeño problema y es que me devuelve el idHabitacion = null y todos sus atributos estan en orden

Comment: Modifica esto leftJoin("reservas", "reservas.idHabitacion", "habitaciones.id") y pon esto leftJoin("reservas", "reservas.idHabitacion", "=",                                   "habitaciones.id")

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas en la documentacion de laravel dice que cuando es comparacion de igualdad no es necesario poner el "="